# Json parsing error - libgdx

Tags: json, libgdx, scene2d

Tying to use a own made skin.json file for styling Scene2d.
But I still getting Json errors and I can't figure out why!

**File named: uiskin2.json**

```
{
com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: { default-font: { file: default.fnt } },
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
  default: { down: default-round-down, up: default-round, font: default-font }
},
com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
  default: { titleFont: default-font },
}
}
```

**Error I'll get:**

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin2.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:97)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.<init>(Skin.java:74)
at Scene2D_UI_Wigets_Skins.Scene2dUi.create(Scene2dUi.java:17)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:147)
at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:124)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error reading file: uiskin2.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:694)
at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Skin.load(Skin.java:95)
... 4 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing file: uiskin2.json
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:77)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.Json.fromJson(Json.java:692)
... 5 more
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.SerializationException: Error parsing JSON, unmatched brace.
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:554)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:55)
at com.badlogic.gdx.utils.JsonReader.parse(JsonReader.java:75)
... 6 more
```

The errors them self aren't saying much about the content within the uiskin2.json file, only parsing errors?

Doe's someone sees it? Do I need to specify default props like `default-round-down`?
What am I missing here?

**p.s**
Testes a skin from the internet which works just fine
[uiskin.json](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets/data)

Comment: You need to format your json better so you can read it easier. Check the answer from Phil and you would have seen the extra comma right away if you formatted it properly. Readability is everything, I would sacrifice a view FPS for extra readability any day without a blink if it would come to it.

Comment: @Menno Gouw - You make a good point. Funnily enough the first thing I did to try to find the problem was to reformat it. Then - as you say - it was obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I see is that you have a spurious comma after the third-from-last closing brace.

Try this...

```
{
  com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
    default-font: {
      file: default.fnt
    }
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: {
      down: default-round-down,
      up: default-round,
      font: default-font
    }
  },
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Window$WindowStyle: {
    default: {
      titleFont: default-font
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out here. Formatting like this does eyes better! But the actual problem was the name of my skin file. For some reason it needs to be named: 'uiskin.json' and nothing else